# Loadbalancing policy in cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What is wrong with the following code, why the load balancing in Cassandra is not working?

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['172.30.56.63','172.30.36.129'], keyspace: 'qnapstat',
                                      policies : { loadBalancing : new cassandra.policies.loadBalancing.RoundRobinPolicy } });

const query = 'SELECT * FROM nodedata WHERE partitionkey = ?';

async function read() {
    console.log(client.options.policies.loadBalancing);
    const params = ['testdata'];
    var response = await client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true, consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.quorum });
    console.log(response.info);
    process.exit();
}

read();
```

I printed the tried hosts, I am able to see It always tries to fetch the 172.30.36.129 as coordinator, Not the other one.

Comment: I just ran your code in my cassandra cluster, and it's working fine as expected. Can you check if first node `172.30.56.63` is up ?

Comment: Working as expected in the sense, can you brief it ?

Comment: I tried in another cluster also, it's not load balancing

Comment: Have u tried with nodejs client ?

Comment: I am using nodejs client only (version 3.3.0). For my cluster (2 nodes), the client connects to each node alternatively with round-robin policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood, Only with the same client connection it will work with that policy, To make it clear the following code works as expected,

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['172.30.56.60','172.30.56.61,172.30.56.62'], keyspace: 'qnapstat', 
                                      policies : { loadBalancing : new cassandra.policies.loadBalancing.RoundRobinPolicy
                         } });

var index = 0;
var totalcount = 10;

const query = 'SELECT readiops FROM nodedata where nodeip = ?';

async function read() {
    console.log(client.options.policies.loadBalancing);
    console.log(client.options.policies.retry);

    while(index < totalcount) {
       const params = ['testdata'];
       var response = await client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true, consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.quorum });
       console.log(response.info);
       index = index + 1;
    }
       process.exit();
}

read();
```

Thanks,

Harry